# Add Raspberry Pi to Mobile Device

Tags: android, ios, wifi, raspberry-pi

- A IoT device (currently Raspberry Pi for prototyping
- Connect and control device over Wifi using mobile device app (iOS and Android)
- Dynamically pair (onboard?) multiple of these devices to app

  - Could be using device WiFi AP or BLE?

I'm specifically looking for an open source solution for pairing a WiFi enabled device to a mobile app. I would imagine there are some open source solutions out there, but I just can't get my search terminology correct.